# Why is it called "Speaker VOTE"?

Tags: word-usage

Why they call "Speaker vote" when clearly there is a voting and not a single vote?

Comment: This is one of the usual definitions of vote as found in a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is sense 1 of "vote" in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vote#Noun): "a formalized choice on legally relevant measures such as employment or appointment to office or a proceeding about a legal dispute".

This is distinct from sense 2: "an act or instance of participating in such a choice, e.g., by submitting a ballot".

Comment: onde example in sense 1 is: "The city council decided the matter should go to public vote." isn't it the same as: "The city council decided the matter should go to public **voting**.? I see no diference

Comment: The difference is that _should go to public vote_ is English, and _should go to public voting_ isn't. _Voting_ is used for the process that happens during a _vote_, so we can certainly talk about _public voting_, but that refers to an activity, not to the event that the activity is part of.

Comment: do you think the use of word "vote" in this case is a way to make it more personal? I mean we know many will vote (that is what I think voting is about) but calling vote kind of singuralize the question to a more personal level. do you think that make sense?

Comment: No, I don't think there's anything personal about it. It is singular because it is conceived of as a singular event. There are other examples in English: _I went for **a run**_. _Let's sit down and have **a talk**_.  _You can have **a wash** upstairs_ (this means "wash yourself", not washing anything else)  You can't use all verbs in this way, but there are several that you can.

Comment: @ Colin Fine, I got it now. Thank you very much

Comment: Can I ask you what consiste the activity of voting?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking

Comment: I mean what compose the activity of voting? what consist, what comprise of the activity of voting

Comment: Won't a dictionary tell you that?