# what is the difference between "vote" and "voting"?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, british-english, learning

the reason I ask this question is that I see in most cases if not all cases "vote" can be replaced by "Voting" right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is it called "Speaker VOTE"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/330446/why-is-it-called-speaker-vote)

Comment: Please refer to a dictionary.  "Voting" is the participle, "-ing form" of the verb "vote".  "vote" is a noun and verb.

Comment: Please don't use the tags "american-english" and "british-english" unless you are asking something specific about American or British usage, or the difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

*Vote* is the normal and *voting* the continuous form. For example:

- I always vote for him. [habit]
- I am voting for him. [currently doing it]

However, when using it as a noun, only *vote* is used.

- Your vote counts.